# How to read screen's named pipe?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen, fifo

For curiosity, I wanted to read a GNU screen session's named pipe.

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    59750.hello     (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-gergely.
```

And indeed there is a named pipe:

```
S-gergely $ ls -l
összesen 4
prw-------. 1 gergely gergely 0 nov   21 11.06 59750.hello
```

I tried to read it with `tail -f`, `cat` and other things to no avail.

Does `(Detached)` mean that there is no flux of data through this named pipe? Only when the screen is active?

UPDATE: it does not work even when that screen is active

Can I read the data with some standard Unix command-line tool?

Comment: You are assuming there something there to read. What if the other end of the pipe is in fact waiting to read instead. I believe it's a two way pipe used by `screen` to talk to its screen daemon process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When data was read from pipe it was gone from pipe. I don't think that it's possible to have multiple readers which can read same data at same time. So when screen is attached, probably screen process read data before tail/cat that you use.